# Highcharts - Segmented column bar

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can I achieve segmented columns using [highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/) like in the photo bellow: [image: segmented columns] I have tried using [column stacked](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked) and format my data in series of 1 but this is very counterintuitive and can't make it work. Is there any builtin option that I can use?

Comment: can you please add snippet what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this demo will be a good start for you to create a chart as in the shared image.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fd0h6o23/

```
  series: [{
    stacking: 'normal',
    color: 'rgb(100,100,200)',
    data: [
      [0, 1],
      [0, 1],
      [0, 1],
      [0, 1],
      [0, 1],
      [0, 1],
      [0, 1],
      [0, 1],
      [0, 1],
      [0, 1],
      [0, 1],
      [0, 1]
    ],
    grouping: false,
    borderWidth: 4,
    borderColor: 'rgb(30,30,70.1)'
  }, {
    stacking: 'normal',
    stack: 'b',
    grouping: false,
    color: 'rgb(200,100,200)',
    data: [
      [0, 1],
      [0, 1],
      [0, 1],
      [0, 1],
      [0, 1],
      [0, 1],
      [0, 1],
      [0, 1],
      [0, 1]
    ],
    borderWidth: 4,
    borderColor: 'rgb(30,30,70, 1)'
  }, {
    stacking: 'normal',
    color: 'rgb(100,100,200)',
    data: [
      [1, 1],
      [1, 1],
      [1, 1],
      [1, 1],
      [1, 1],
      [1, 1],
      [1, 1],
      [1, 1],
      [1, 1],
      [1, 1],
      [1, 1],
      [1, 1]
    ],
    grouping: false,
    borderWidth: 4,
    borderColor: 'rgb(30,30,70.1)'
  }, {
    stacking: 'normal',
    stack: 'b',
    grouping: false,
    color: 'rgb(200,100,200)',
    data: [
      [1, 1],
      [1, 1],
      [1, 1],
      [1, 1],
      [1, 1],
      [1, 1],
    ],
    borderWidth: 4,
    borderColor: 'rgb(30,30,70, 1)'
  }]
```

---

EDIT

I also found other useful examples:

- https://jsfiddle.net/jsotma6a/
- https://jsfiddle.net/d_paul/t7uu122p/
- https://www.highcharts.com/samples/highcharts/studies/dotplot-equalizer

More you can find under searching for the "Highcharts equalizer chart".